# Как менять цены в интернет магазине на Битриксе?

Tags: битрикс

Достался по наследству мне интернет магазин на Битриксе. Вопрос не могу разобраться как менять цены.

Comment: может смешной вопрос конечно))) ссылка на магаз  http://www.doorman.ru/

Comment: очень срочно нужно поменять)

Comment: Shrek, спс))) нашла)

Comment: Я ответом сделал, можешь его принять :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, цена там в каталоге меняется. Cлева, все от версии битрикса немного зависит, разные морды.

А так, слева меню, там каталог, там можно глядеть.

Comment: Боюсь уже и след простыл) +1

Comment: я тоже боюсь :)

Comment: ну что вы так))))

Comment: спс, друзья, уже поменяла, эту чушь)

Comment: Удачи :) на поприще.